# vix futures vega per contract and tvix vega per share

Tags: vix, spx

How much vega in spx terms (straddle contracts) or dollar value is in 10 vix futures contacts and 10000 shares of tvix

Comment: Vega of a future is fixed at 1000 USD per contract. Vega of a straddle varies. You tell me the price (or implied vol) and quantity of the straddle and I will compute for you the vega. Vega of TVIX can be found by looking up how many futures it has.